# php mysql finding rows older than a day from date feald

Tags: php, mysql, database, time

Here is how it should be:

1. search the database for uploads older than  a day.
2. output the id's for the uploads in a list.

here is what I have so far:

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$connect = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);

$timestamp = strtotime("-1 days");
$efined = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE timestamp < '$timestamp'");
$efound = mysql_query($efined);
$enum = mysql_numrows($efound);
$ecount = 0;
echo $enum.'records were found.';
while ($ecount < $enum) {
    $euid = mysql_result($efound,$ecount,"uid");
    echo $euid.'<br>';
    $ecount++;
}
mysql_close($connect);
?>
```

currently, this outputs nothing, when there is a record 3 days old.
How would I spesify the date format? in my database, it looks like this: 2013-04-02.
thanks for any help,
josh.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

this

```
   $enum=mysql_numrows($efound);
```

should be

```
  $enum=mysql_num_rows($efound);
```

EDIT.

try your sql like that

```
   where  timestamp < date('now', '-1 days')
```

edit:

you are defining two `mysql_query`

change this

```
    $efined = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE timestamp < '$timestamp'");
```

to

```
   $efined = "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE timestamp < '$timestamp'";
```

Comment: the second one wasn't in the original question, I guess it's just a typo of the editor (original question code was really a mess)

Comment: hello, sorry i'm using a screanreader and can't use the toolbar. I'll go try this code. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistake...

```
$efined = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE timestamp < '$timestamp'");
$efound=mysql_query($efined);
$enum=mysql_numrows($efound);
```

There must be only one query and wrong num_rows name...

```
$sql= "SELECT * FROM uploads WHERE timestamp < '$timestamp'";
$efound = mysql_query($sql);
$enum = mysql_num_rows($efound);
```

P.S. The old myslq functions support ends at PHP 5.4 . Its good for you to start using myslqi or PDO mysql !